# Wordpress easier way then pulling each post ID separately?

Tags: wordpress-theming

I am trying to learn this stuff but there are multiple ways to skin a cat. I have a few posts in WP that I am using as content blocks on the home page. For each block I am using

```
<?php
 $post_id = 34;
 $queried_post = get_post($post_id);
 $title = $queried_post->post_title;
 echo $queried_post->post_content; 
 ?>
```

Then in a different area I am using

```
<?php
 $post_id = 35;
 $queried_post = get_post($post_id);
 $title = $queried_post->post_title;
 echo $queried_post->post_content; 
 ?>
```

Is this the right way to structure a custom homepage?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
   <?php
 $post_ID_Array = array(1, 10, 3, 4);//All the Post IDs you need
    foreach ($post_ID_Array as $postID)://Iterate through all the IDs
      $the_article = new WP_Query('p='.$postID);/*Retrieve the post*/  
      while ($the_article->have_posts()) : $the_article->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="post-details post-<?php echo $postID?>">
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                </div><!--.post-details-->
  <?php
    endwhile;
    endforeach;?>
```

You can then style each section individually using .post-{postID} e.g *.post-34{}*. You can also style all the posts using *.post-details*